# Apply dynamic css styles to drop down list items in Oracle jet

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, oracle-jet

Here is my drop down list

```
<select id="productselect" aria-label="Single Select"      
        data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect', disabled: false,
                  value: productValue,optionChange: onChangeProduct,
                  rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:20em'}}">
   <!-- ko foreach: products -->
      <option data-bind="value:value, text:label, css:{labelclass:true}">   
      </option>    
   <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

I would like to apply different colors to each list item by passing dynamic class, but not working. Please help.

Drop-down should be like

```
<option style = "color : red" data-bind="value:value, text:label">
<option style = "color : blue" data-bind="value:value, text:label">
and so on...
```

How to achieve this type of drop-down dynamically.

Comment: Are you seeing any error? a jsfiddle would help us better to fix the issue

Comment: No. I am not getting any error. I am doing it using Oracle jet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css binding is not working for above type of select component.
I had to go with this type and it is working fine as expected.

```
<ul id="prods" style="display: none" >
   <!-- ko foreach: prods -->
    <li data-bind="attr: {'oj-data-value': value}, style:
         {color:colorString}">
      <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
   </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<select id="prodselect" name="prod_names"
    data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect', disabled: true,
               renderMode: 'jet',list: 'prods', value: product,
               rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:100%'}}">
</select>
```

Passing required information from back end through 'prod' data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `css` binding usually has a logic test so you can decide which classes to apply, but you are passing `true`, so it's applying the CSS class `labelclass` to every option.

If you want to show either red or blue using classes, change your HTML markup to:

```
<option data-bind="value: value, text: label, css: computedLabelClass">
```

And change your JavaScript view model to add:

```
this.computedLabelClass = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return <your logic test here> ? "redLabelClass" : "blueLabelClass";
});
```